# Duplicate entries inside loop of list<String>

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am using the following code and at the end i saw in calssEntries list the last values duplicated 
i mean if i debug it i can see the right data but in the second iteration the values of the first data entries
are override and i see the second twice and so on 
what i miss here?

```
String memberName = null;
String memberValue = null;
List<String> memberList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> memberValueList = new ArrayList<String>();+ArrayList<ClassEntry> calssEntries = new ArrayList<ClassEntry>();

...
while (dataRow != null) {
    memberList.clear();
    memberValueList.clear();

    for (int i = 1; i < dataArray.length; i += 2) {         
        memberName = dataArray[i];
        memberList.add(memberName);
        memberValue = dataArray[i + 1];
        memberValueList.add(memberValue);
    }

    ClassEntry classEntry = new ClassEntry();
    classEntry.setClassName(className);
    classEntry.setMemberName(memberList);
    classEntry.setMemberValue(memberValueList);
    calssEntries.add(classEntry);


....
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is ClassEntry an object you defined?

Comment: You should really format your code properly... see that `edit` link there, use it, if you see your code formatted badly after posting the question.

Comment: Your intentional misspelling of calssEntries makes my copyediting brain go nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you need to create a new instance of memberList and memberValueList in the while loop. Something like:

```
calssEntries = new ArrayList<ClassEntry>();

...
while (dataRow != null) {
List<String> memberList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> memberValueList = new ArrayList<String>();
...
...
```

In your code, entries of calssEntries are referring to the same(single) instance of memberList and memberValue.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for (int i = 1; i < dataArray.length; i += 2) {

  int j = i;

  memberName = dataArray[i];              
  memberList.add(memberName);                
  memberValue = dataArray[j + 1]; 
  memberValueList.add(memberValue);

}
```

Comment: `int j = i;` is superfluous.